# How to get the max timestamp row from a given table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the max timestamp rows based of a group of `software_image_build_id and variant`

Here is my SQL fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ed643/1 ,it should output the max timestamp rows for a combination for software_image_build_id and variant  ,I tried as follows but it is not helping,can anyone provide guidance on how to fix it?

```
SELECT software_image_build,MAX(timestamp) FROM software_image_builds where software_image_id=1452
group by software_image_build
```

Comment: Do you want the row with max timestamp?

Comment: @AshishLohia - yes

Comment: Check my query. Add if it didn't work.

Comment: Make up your mind. Do you want 'a row based on the MAX value (of timestamp) of another row', as per your title, or 'the row with max timestamp', as per your answer to @AshishLohia's comment?

Comment: I think he just wants the row where the timestamp is max filtered on the id. I believe I have solved his problem. But, there is no response.

Comment: @AshishLohia With respect, I'm not interested in what you believe. It is of no relevance. I am asking the OP.

Comment: @Ashish - My bad ,I updated by sqfiddle @ sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ed643/1,I need to print the max timestamp row for a group of software_image_id and variant

Comment: @user3508811, edited the answer.

Comment: @user3508811 - i have updated my query and screenshot with expected variant column too.

Comment: Fiddles are great, but see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use inner query to get the data along with max timestamp and then using an outer query get the data by software_image_id and variant to ensure you are getting correct data with their max timestamp.

```
SELECT OUTSIDE.*
FROM software_image_builds OUTSIDE, 
   (SELECT software_image_id, variant, MAX(timestamp) as maxtimestamp
    FROM software_image_builds
    GROUP BY software_image_id, variant) AS INSIDE
WHERE OUTSIDE.software_image_id = INSIDE.software_image_id
AND OUTSIDE.variant = INSIDE.variant
AND OUTSIDE.timestamp = INSIDE.maxtimestamp
```

[image]

Comment: I only want for a specific `software_image_id=1452`

Comment: but the software_image_build corresponding to it is `CI_LA.UM.5.8-02200-8x98.1-20`, want row with max timestamp

Comment: so remove it from SELECT query, updated the query & screenshots both again so now you can view only MAX timestamp

Comment: I want row with max timestamp ,not the max timestamp

Comment: ok, updated the query and screenshot to get the expected row with max timestamp

Comment: @user3508811 - did you check my latest query and screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

The result seems correct , what result do you want?
This sql get the software_image_build and the max timestamp every software_image_build.

If you want to get the max timestamp across all data ,dont't use group by.

```
SELECT software_image_build,MAX(timestamp) FROM software_image_builds where software_image_id=1452
```

If you want to get every software_image_build,and split the max timestamp every row,try the following query:

```
SELECT S.software_image_build,A.max_timestamp 
FROM software_image_builds AS S,
(SELECT software_image_build,MAX(timestamp) as max_timestamp 
  FROM software_image_builds where software_image_id=1452) 
  AS A
group by S.software_image_build
```

output this :

```
software_image_build            max_timestamp
CI_LA.UM.5.8-02200-8x98.1-16    2017-07-14T21:51:02Z
CI_LA.UM.5.8-02200-8x98.1-20    2017-07-14T21:51:02Z
CI_LA.UM.5.8-60402-8x98.1-1     2017-07-14T21:51:02Z
```

Comment: I want row with max timestamp

Comment: SELECT S.software_image_build,A.max_timestamp FROM software_image_builds AS S,(SELECT software_image_build,MAX(timestamp) as max_timestamp FROM software_image_builds where software_image_id=1452) AS A
group by S.software_image_build

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you have now posted:

```
SELECT software_image_build,max(timestamp)
FROM software_image_builds
WHERE software_image_id=1452
GROUP BY software_image_build,variant
LIMIT 1
```

outputs:

```
software_image_build            timestamp
CI_LA.UM.5.8-02200-8x98.1-16    2017-07-13T18:38:41Z
CI_LA.UM.5.8-02200-8x98.1-20    2017-07-14T21:51:02Z
CI_LA.UM.5.8-60402-8x98.1-1     2017-02-28T15:08:10Z
```

which appears to be exactly what you now say you wanted. If not, further clarification is required.

Comment: @EFP - My bad ,I updated by sqfiddle @ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ed643/1,I need to print the `max timestamp row` for a group of software_image_id and variant

Comment: Same difference. Get rid of MAX and use ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 1.

Comment: @EJP - if there are multiple rows with id 1452 with maximum timestamp then your query would only return 1 record. With my query it would return all the rows that have id 1452 and maximum timestamp.

Comment: @JRG He keeps talking about '*a*' row' and '*the* row'.

Comment: @EJP - It should print four rows namely  1452 with OS_DEF and OS_PERF with the maxtimetamp row  and the same wiht 1453 with OS_DEF and OS_PERF

Comment: @user3508811 So for heaven's sake *clarify your question.* Don't poke essential information like that down here in comments where nobody else can see it. You have repeatedly used the expressions '*a* row' and '*the* row', which flatly contradict what you have just stated in your comment.

Comment: @EJP - Sorry about any confusion,I updated my question,hope its clear now

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM software_image_builds where software_image_id=1452 
   AND timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) as timestamp from  
  software_image_builds 
 where software_image_id=1452)
```

check in fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/729532/44

Comment: ,can you check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ed643/1 ,I am looking for the maxtimestamp row for a group of software_image_build and variant

Comment: u need group of all is it

Comment: please check fiddle now

Answer (score -1):

select * from software_image_builds where timestamp in (SELECT MAX(timestamp)
                                                      FROM software_image_builds group by 
                                                       software_image_id, variant );

Comment: I want row with max timestamp ,this is just giving the maxtimestamp but not the corresponding row

Comment: @AshishLohia - there is no column by name variant in fiddle table schema?

Comment: OP added a new fiddle.

Comment: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ed643/1

Answer (score -1):

You can order the results by the timestamp column and then use limit to return only the first result.

```
SELECT software_image_build, timestamp FROM software_image_builds where
software_image_id=1452 group by software_image_build order by timestamp DESC     
limit 1
```